# Why does Internet Explorer 9 throw "member not found" js error in dojo 1.4.6?

Tags: javascript, dojo

It's very weird but I get "member not found" js error and I can't figure out a problem. I have 2 users in windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9. One user can't see this error, another user can see this error.

Place in dojo.js file where this error occurs:

```
_fixEvent: function(/*Event*/ evt, /*DOMNode*/ sender){
    if(!evt){
        var w = sender && (sender.ownerDocument || sender.document || sender).parentWindow || window;
        evt = w.event; 
    }
    if(!evt){return(evt);}
        evt.target = evt.srcElement;
```

Trying to set evt.target throws js error. I see DispDomMouseEvent element in debug mode on user where the error exists and I see [object][MouseEvent] where it doesn't occur.
Could you help me and point me out this problem? I appreciate any help.

Comment: There's really not nearly enough context to go on here, but I'll take a wild shot in the dark based on the browser in question and guess that maybe you're running into [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802397/ie9-ie10-events-can-be-sent-to-the-wrong-listeners).

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will look into it. Also I forgot to add that this error is reproducible only in standards mode of IE.

Comment: If I put all _fixEvent code into try/catch block I see good work as another browsers show and after looking into dojo versions I see it could be reproducible before 1.7 version because there is checking evt.target on exist before setting new value for evt.target

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens if you use the event object inside an async method (setTimeout, setInterval, any kind of async)

You must clone the event object and use the cloned event.